# is it possible to get client latency from server in gRPC?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grpc

As I work on a game that timing of clients is important, I need to know exactly when a request sent by a client. is it to get clients latency from client to server? for example time it toke to receive client message in server.

I know, I can use a ping request from server to the client and calculate some average but i think its not an accurate approach and has mistakes.

Comment: You could get the time from the client (to be safe at specific time zone) and send this with the message.

Comment: @IsolatedSushi cheats? clock of everyone at same timezone is the same?

Comment: I meant that it would still work when someone from a different time zone plays the game  compared to the server

Comment: @IsolatedSushi i understand what you mean but its not a good solution. users can be anywhere with different ping and network speed

Comment: I may be wrong, but I wouldn't think this would be possible.The server can only read what it received, and only the client knows when it was sent. You can send the timestamp from the client like IsolatedSushi suggested, but again, it opens the door for cheating. There have been many different solutions to solving netcode problems over the years though, and I'd recommend learning from past efforts. Examples that come to mind are client side prediction, snapshot interpolation, buffering, and extrapolation.. Are these possible solutions for you?

Comment: Your idea to calculate the ping average is probably your best option... this is network programming nothing is accurate or guaranteed to be mistake free unfortunately